# What to do when a load balancer health check comes back with status code mismatch error

Tags: cloud

My health check for load balancer brings back status code mismatch error.

Tried terminating and recreating. Tried editing the port and interval timeout range. None of this has worked. I need a step by step to work with. Thanks